# how to link text of text view to web site

Tags: android, textview

i know this is damn simple ques ..but i went hrough many tutorial with many ways ..can u just tell me the simplest way to link text in text view to web site dynamically..means i dont want to include link name to text which will b shown likw href tag in web..hope u a;; getting my prob.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="PoliticiansNpolitics.in"
        android:textColor="#4169E1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

i Want ABOVE TEXT tO redirect to google.com upon click

Answer (score 1):

You can give click listener to text view as below

```
 tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            });
```

Where `tv`  is id of your textview

Comment: that what i dont want to put link name in text . i dont want to show link name in text..upon click on text it should direct it